# Example of a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

What is the smallest simple Graph with all but one nodes having degree 3. The last node having degree 2?

I have tried looking for relevant Graph Theory books but couldn't find how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph must have at least 4 vertices, for any to have degree three.
Since the sum of the degrees is always even, this graph must have an even number of degree three vertices. So the total number of vertices (including the one degree 2 vertex) in this smallest graph has to be odd.
So the graph has at least 5 vertices (it can't have 4).

[image]

So you can't get a smaller graph than this with your degree conditions.